# Cookie not set in live server but in localhost

Tags: java, scala, ssl, cookies, https

I have been developing website with scala(java-based language) and I use HttpOnly cookie to identify users.

And I can see the "Set-Cookie" header in the browser's network tab. But the cookie is not set.

I tried to run server in localhost and it was fine. But when I run in host server, it's not set.

Below is when I run in localhost.
[image]

Here is when I run on the host server.
[image]

[image]

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the header the cookie was set for? Share with us the code used to set the cookie. Also what about the secure flag?

Comment: Please review the configuration of deployed application, namely - make sure cookie Domain and Path attributes appreciates URL of the LIVE application. If your frontend is accessible by different host than your LIVE application, please check out cookie SameSite attribute for the appropriate value to work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem for me was that I was using both `http` + `secure` cookie. `secure` can only be used with `https` (the only exception to this is on localhost). Setting up `https` would be more work for me at the moment for my prototyping, so I just removed setting the cookie as `secure`, and my problem was fixed.